# Clicking on div over transparent image

Tags: javascript, html, css

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/z1y8zuxf/1/)

I have a gallery of images with a div in the top-right corner of each image. I want to trigger an event when that div is clicked. However, when the image is transparent (`opacity = 0.1`) it seems clicking the div doesn't trigger the event, even though it works fine when the image isn't transparent. What is causing this, and how can I ensure the event handler is still triggered?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `z-index` to `.hover`

```
.hover {
   z-index:9;
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('hover1').onclick = testClick;
document.getElementById('hover2').onclick = testClick;
document.getElementById('hover3').onclick = testClick;

function testClick(event) {
 // this works for hover2 and hover3 but not hover3
  document.getElementById('log').innerText = event.currentTarget.id;
}
```

```css
.imgHover {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hover {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index:9;
}

.transparent {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgHover">
  <div id="hover1" class="hover">Hide</div>
  <img id="img1" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.24.2/img/champion/Aatrox.png" alt="" class="transparent" />
</div>
<div class="imgHover">
  <div id="hover2" class="hover">Hide</div>
  <img id="img2" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.24.2/img/champion/Ahri.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="imgHover">
  <div id="hover3" class="hover">Hide</div>
  <img id="img3" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.24.2/img/champion/Akali.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="log">output:</div>
```

Comment: man, you're quick :)

Comment: Thanks! I try my best ;)

Answer (score 3):

Please add `z-index: 99;` to the hover class.
Here's [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1y8zuxf/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.imgHover div{
  z-index:5;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n8h35y2s/)